# Golang выборка из базы

Tags: sql, golang, select

Есть метод:

```
type SelectNar struct {

  Id            int64   `json:"id"`
  IdPatient     int64   `json:"id_patient"`
  NumberNar     string  `json:"number_nar"`
  DateOpenNar       string  `json:"date_open_nar"`
  VrachOrtoped      string  `json:"vrach_ortoped"`
  DateStartProduction   string  `json:"date_start_production"`
  VrachTechnic      string  `json:"vrach_technic"`
  DateCloseNar      string  `json:"date_close_nar"`
  Sum           string  `json:"sum"`
}

func EditModelListNarGet(id string) []*SelectNar {
    rows := db.Select(`
    SELECT
    j_nar.id, j_nar.number_nar, j_nar.date_open_nar, j_catalog_vrach.fam as vrach_ortoped,
    j_nar.date_start_production, j_catalog_vrach_1.fam as vrach_technic,
    j_nar.date_close_nar, j_nar.sum
    FROM
    (j_nar LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach ON j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped = j_catalog_vrach.id)
    Left JOIN j_catalog_vrach AS j_catalog_vrach_1 ON j_nar.id_vrach_technic = j_catalog_vrach_1.id
    WHERE j_nar.id_patient = $1`, id)

    bks := make([]*SelectNar, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(SelectNar)
        rows.Scan(&bk.Id, &bk.NumberNar, &bk.DateOpenNar, &bk.VrachOrtoped, &bk.DateStartProduction, &bk.VrachTechnic, &bk.DateCloseNar, &bk.Sum)
        fmt.Println(bk)
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks
}

func Select(Query string, Args ...interface{}) *sql.Rows {
    db, _ := db()
    fmt.Println(Args...)
    rows, err := db.Query(Query, Args...)
    if(err != nil){
        log.Fatal(err)
        db.Close()
    }else {
        return rows
        db.Close()

    }
    fmt.Println(rows)
    return rows
}
```

В rows попадает результат запроса только в эти поля:
&bk.Id, &bk.NumberNar, &bk.DateOpenNar
дальше

```
(где в запросе, начинается 
 j_catalog_vrach.fam as vrach_ortoped,
     j_nar.date_start_production, j_catalog_vrach_1.fam as vrach_technic,
     j_nar.date_close_nar, j_nar.sum
)
```

в:
 &bk.VrachOrtoped, &bk.DateStartProduction, &bk.VrachTechnic, &bk.DateCloseNar, &bk.Sum данные не подставляются.
Что может быть не так?

Похоже проблема в том, что некоторые поля получаемые из запроса, пустые т.е NULL...

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с данными, попробуй просто сделать запрос (через psql или pgadmin3): `SELECT
    j_nar.id,
    j_nar.number_nar,
    j_nar.date_open_nar,
    j_nar.date_start_production,
    j_nar.date_close_nar,
    j_nar.sum,
    ortoped.fam as vrach_ortoped,
    technic.fam as vrach_technic
FROM j_nar
LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach AS ortoped ON (j_nar.id_vrach_ortoped = ortoped.id)
LEFT JOIN j_catalog_vrach AS technic ON (j_nar.id_vrach_technic = technic.id)` и посмотреть заполняются-ли поля `vrach_ortoped` и `vrach_technic`

Comment: Запрос выполняется и вся инфа получается, через pssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, если поля пустые присутствуют в наборе (кроме последнего), в Rows дальше все будет пустым, обрабатывай нулевые значения в запросе. К примеру допиши:   `... coalesce( j_nar.id, 0) ...` и так ко всем, т.е. если он пустой то подставить 0.